# How to use inArray and make awesome TicTacToe (Noughts and Crosses) with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I made a TicTacToe Game! Just for fun. It works and all, but can't tell once someone has won. I used .inArray to look for winning solutions on the current board. The idea is once a winning combination of squares is on the board, an alert will pop up ("You won Bruh"). Maybe the inArray is comparing the win arrays to the chosen elements opposed to the elements of the win arrays to the chosen elements? I'm stumped. Check out the jsfiddle if you're interested and leave a response if you've figured it out. Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/QH6W9/7/

//**UPDATE**

I ended up using a magic square and checking if combinations of 3 added to 15 and implemented self teaching and basic AI using possible combinations and a MySQL db. I used a second script to let the computer play itself and build up the database. It's not the most perfect code but see for yourself..

```
//---//--//--//--//--//--//---//--//--//--//--//---//  
//   TIC-TAC-TOE:                                  //
//Good Old game. This version is meant to be a self//
//teaching system as a means to utilise and master //
//exchange between web-page, server and database.  //
//---//--//--//--//--//--//---//--//--//--//--//---//  

// Author: Dylan Madisetti
// Date: I don't remember?


$(document).ready(function(){

    var magiclist = [8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2]; //for humans          
    var squares = [8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2];  //Le Magic Square\\ 
    var xs = [];                         //------------//
    var os = [];                         //  8 | 3 | 4 //
    var x = 0;                           //----+---+---//
    var o = 0;                           //  1 | 5 | 9 //
    var gameover = -1;                   //----+---+---//
    var FirstMoves = [];                 //  6 | 7 | 2 //
    var SecondMoves = [];                //------------//
    var ThirdMoves = [];    //All Diagonals,rows and Columns add to 15\\            
    var moves = [];
    var i = 0;
    win = false;
    end = false;
    // I have a radio button for whether the human plays as x or o     
          if(document.getElementById('human').checked) {
              humanmove("x",x,xs,moves,squares,gameover,i,magiclist,"o",o,os); //human move    
          }else{
              ajaxmove("x",x,xs,moves,squares,gameover,i,magiclist,"o",o,os); //computer move
            x++;
            i++;             
            humanmove("o",o,os,moves,squares,gameover,i,magiclist,"x",x,xs); //human move
          };                
});
```

---

```
//---//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//---//  
// AjaxMove Desc. Checks if can win or block if it//
//can't, Sends data to MYSQLtest which in turn    //
//queries xos database and returns best move is   //
//then used.                                      //
//---//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//---//

function ajaxmove(status,counter,turn,moves,squares,gameover,i,magiclist,otherturn){

bestmove = 0;
if (turn.length >= 2){ //goes through each possibility
     FirstMoves = turn.slice(0);
     while (FirstMoves.length > 1){                        
           FirstX = FirstMoves[0];
           SecondMoves = FirstMoves.slice(1);
           ThirdMoves = squares.slice(0);
           $.each (SecondMoves,function(){
                if (ThirdMoves.length > 0){
                                     SecondX = this;
                         $.each (ThirdMoves,function(){
                             ThirdX = this;
                             if (FirstX + SecondX + ThirdX == 15){
                             bestmove = this;
                             };
                         });
                       ThirdMoves = ThirdMoves.slice(1);                                
                 };
           });
           FirstMoves = FirstMoves.slice(1); 
     }
};
if ((bestmove == 0) && (otherturn.length >= 2)){
     FirstMoves = otherturn.slice(0);
     while (FirstMoves.length > 1){
           FirstX = FirstMoves[0];
           SecondMoves = FirstMoves.slice(1);
           ThirdMoves = squares.slice(0);
           $.each (SecondMoves,function(){
                if (ThirdMoves.length > 0){
                      SecondX = this;
                         $.each (ThirdMoves,function(){
                             ThirdX = this;
                             if (FirstX + SecondX + ThirdX == 15){
                                 bestmove = this;
                             };
                         });
                       ThirdMoves = ThirdMoves.slice(1);                                
                 };
           });
           FirstMoves = FirstMoves.slice(1); 
     }  
};
if (bestmove == 0){
    $.ajax({type:'POST',
        async: false,
        url:'/XOsAI/MYSQLtest.php',
        data:{
            status: status,
            moves: moves,
            remaining: squares,
            gameover: gameover
        },
        success: 
            function(data){
                 bestmove = data;                                           
            }
   });
};
bestmove = Number(bestmove);
index = squares.indexOf(bestmove);
    turn[counter] = bestmove; 
select = magiclist.indexOf(bestmove);
    $('.square').eq(select).addClass(status);
    $('.square').eq(select).addClass('clicked');
    squares.splice(index,1);
    moves[i] = turn[counter];          
    gamecheck(turn,squares,moves); //game check (see below)
    if (win) {
         alert ("You Lose!");
         while (i <= 9){                          
               i++;
               moves[i] = "'" + status + "'";                      
         };                                   
         $.ajax({type:'POST',
               async: false,
               url:'/XOsAI/MYSQLtest.php',
               data:{
                    status: status,
                    moves: moves,
                    remaining: squares,
                    gameover: gameover
              }                      
        });
   };
};
```

---

```
//---//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//---//  
// HumanMove Desc. Allows human to make a move and//
//checks if they have won.Updates Database if so. //
//Also Triggers computer move.                    //
//---//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//---//

function humanmove(status,counter,turn,
              moves,squares,gameover,
              i,magiclist,otherstatus,
              othercounter,otherturn){      
  $(".XOs").on('click', '.square:not(.clicked)', function() {
       if (gameover == -1){
       if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
              $(this).addClass('clicked');
              $(this).addClass(status);
              data = magiclist[$('.square').index(this)];
              turn[counter] = data;
              index = squares.indexOf(data);
              squares.splice(index,1);
              moves[i] = turn[counter];
              gamecheck(turn,squares,moves); //game check (see below)
              if (!(end)){
              if (win) {
                      alert ("You Win!");
                      gameover = 1;
                      while (i <= 9){                          
                          i++;
                          moves[i] = "'" + status + "'";                      
                      };                                  
                      $.ajax({type:'POST',
                           async: false,
                           url:'/XOsAI/MYSQLtest.php',
                           data:{
                               status: status,
                               moves: moves,
                               remaining: squares,
                               gameover: gameover
                           }                     
                      });
                      $('.squares').addClass('clicked');
              };
              counter++;
              i++;
              if (gameover == -1){
              ajaxmove(otherstatus,othercounter,otherturn,moves,squares,gameover,i,magiclist,turn); //computer move           
              othercounter++;
              i++;
              if (win) {gameover = 1;};
              };
              }; 
       };
    };
  });
};
```

---

```
//---//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//---//  
//  GameCheck Desc. Runs through each possibility.//
//As data locations of divs are arranged in magic //
//square, checks if any three add to 15. Checks   //
//for cat game as well.                           //
//---//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//---//  

function gamecheck(turn,squares,moves){ 
    if (turn.length >= 3){
       FirstMoves = turn.slice(0);
       while (FirstMoves.length >= 3){                        
           FirstX = FirstMoves[0];
           SecondMoves = FirstMoves.slice(1);
           ThirdMoves = SecondMoves.slice(1);
           $.each (SecondMoves,function(){
                if (ThirdMoves.length > 0){
                      SecondX = this;
                         $.each (ThirdMoves,function(){
                             ThirdX = this;
                             if (FirstX + SecondX + ThirdX == 15){
                                 win = true;
                             };
                         });
                       ThirdMoves = ThirdMoves.slice(1);                                
                 };
           });
           FirstMoves = FirstMoves.slice(1); 
       }
   };

  if (!(squares.length > 0) && win == false) { //if any remain      
       alert ("You Draw!");
       gameover = 1;
       moves[9] = "'c'";                                                             
       $.ajax({type:'POST',  //ajax to tell server Cat Game
               async: false,
               url:'/XOsAI/MYSQLtest.php',
               data:{
                    status: "c",
                    moves: moves,
                    remaining: squares,
                    gameover: gameover
               }                      
       });
       end = true;
  };
};
```

---

and the php if anyone is interested

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1) Connect to mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$databaseName);
$dbs = mysqli_select_db($con,$databaseName);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2) Query database for bestmove or insert data if gameover
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$gameover = 0;
$col = 0;
$status = $_POST['status'];
$moves = $_POST['moves'];
$gameover = $_POST['gameover'];
$remaining = $_POST['remaining'];
$bestresult = 0;
if ($gameover < 0){
  $required = (count($remaining) * 50); //seemed large enough to make a smart move
  if (count($moves) > 0){
    foreach ($moves as $move){
      $columns[$col].=' AND ';
      $columns[$col].= '`';
      $columns[$col].= ($col + 1);
      $columns[$col].= '`=';
      $columns[$col].= $move;
      $col++;
    };    
  $moves = implode(' ',$columns); 
  };
  $sql = '
            SELECT *
            FROM xos
            WHERE status=\'';
  $sql .= $status;
  $sql .= '\' ';
  if (count($moves) > 0){
    $sql .= $moves ;
  };
  $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //fetch result
  $results = $results->num_rows;
  echo $con->error; 
if ($results > $required){
        if (count($moves) == 0){
          $col = 1;
      };
      $reset = $sql;
      foreach ($remaining as $bestmove){
          $sql .=' AND ';
          $sql .= '`';
          $sql .= $col;              
          $sql .= '`='; 
          $sql .= $bestmove;
          $sql .= ' ';
          $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
          $results = $results->num_rows;
          if ($con->error){
              echo $con->error ."\n";
              echo $sql .":";
              echo $results ."\n \n";
          }
          if ($results >= $bestresult){
              $bestresult = $results;
              $bestplay = $bestmove;
          };
          $sql = $reset;
      };  
}else{
    $sql = '
           SELECT *
           FROM xos
           WHERE status=\'c\'';
    if (count($moves) > 0){
        $sql .=' AND ';
        $sql .= $moves ;
    };
   $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql); //fetch result
   $results = $results->num_rows;
    if ($results > $required){
          if (count($moves) == 0){
          $col = 1;
        };
        $reset = $sql;
        foreach ($remaining as $bestmove){
          $sql .=' AND ';
          $sql .= '`';
          $sql .= $col;              
          $sql .= '`='; 
          $sql .= $bestmove;
          $sql .= ' ';
          $results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
          $results = $results->num_rows;
          if ($con->error){
              echo $con->error ."\n";
              echo $sql .":";
              echo $results ."\n \n";
          }
          if ($results >= $bestresult){
              $bestresult = $results;
              $bestplay = $bestmove;
          };
          $sql = $reset;
      };
    }else{
    $max = count($remaining) - 1;
    $bestplay = rand(0,$max);
    $bestplay= $remaining[$bestplay];
    };
  };echo $bestplay;
}else{
$sql = "INSERT INTO `xos`(`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `Status`) VALUES (";
      for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
          $sql .= $moves[$i];
          $sql .= ",";
      };
      $sql .= "";
      $sql .= $moves[9];
      $sql .= ")";
      if ($con->query($sql) === false){
          echo $con->error;
          echo $sql;
      };     
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

First, you are putting all of the locations of `.x` into an array, and then seeing if that array is in the `wins` array.

Unfortunately, `$.inArray()` will only return an index if the items are *the same* item, not if they have matching values.

```
$.inArray([4,5,6], [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) // returns -1  

var ary1 = [1,2,3];
var ary2 = [4,5,6];
$.inArray(ary2, [ary1, ary2]); // returns 1

$.inArray(ary2, [ary1, [4,5,6]]); // returns -1
```

Secondly, if you are at a state in the game where you have more than 3 X's, you will never match a winning position:

```
X O _
X X O
X O _
```

In this case `xs` will equal `[1,4,5,7]`.  This is a winning position, but will not match any of your arrays.

There are a number of other ways to go about this.  The easiest, given your `wins` array, is to iterate through each and check if the `div` at each location in the array is an `X`.  If so, stop and declare a win.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/4BDwt/1/

Note, I cleaned up some other code in this example.

- Removed the redundant `clickable` class, and use
  `.square:not(.clicked)`.
- Replaced `.click()` with `.on()`.
- Removed the `.square` IDs and just use the `div` order in `XOs` as the location, using `.eq()` with the array position.  IDs shouldn't start with numbers, and it is better to store data in a jQuery data attribute, like `<div data-location="1">`, and retrieve it with `.data('location')`.  But, in this case, it wasn't needed as the div order tells us where it is.
- Replaced `$(array).each(function(){})` with `$.each(array, function(){})`.  This is the correct way to iterate over a normal array that is not jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and .eq() suggestion. I finished the program complete with AI awhile back, but just got round to posting what I finally did. I'm not going to post the link for security reasons, but it consistently draws or wins.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it looks like in

```
$(wins).each(function(){
    var maybe = $.inArray(this,xs); //if Xs match combos win
    ...
}
```

you're checking if the `array xs` is found in the currently checked winning combination instead of just comparing `this` to `xs` (both 1-dimensional arrays). [Tried `$.inArray(wins, xs)` but it won't work.]

Could this be it?

**UPDATE:** this version works: http://jsfiddle.net/QH6W9/9/

I fixed your code to retrieve the ids of the X'ed fields with this:

```
var xs = $(".x").map(function(i, el) {
             return parseInt($(el).attr('id'))
         }).get(); // get ids as array
```

And also the detection of the win situation:

```
$(wins).each(function() {
    var found = true;
    for(var i =0; i<this.length; i++) {
        found &= ($.inArray(this[i], xs) > -1);
    }
    if (!found) return;
    alert("You Won Bruh");
    var all = $(".square");
    $(all).addclass('clicked'); //stops more turns
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You had two problems in your program:

First, you had the following:

parseInt(number);
   xs[i] = number;

`xs[i]` was still getting a string because `parseInt()` does not modify its parameter.  Instead, it returns the numeric value.  So I changed that code to the more compact:

```
xs[i] = parseInt(number);
```

Secondly, in your `$(wins).each()` loop, you were using `$.inArray()`, but you already *have* the individual array, so you really wanted to do an array subset comparison there.  Since Javascript/jQuery has no built-in array subset function, I just compared each element in the array:

```
$(wins).each(function(){
    console.log( 'template: ' + this );
    var allIn = true;
    for( var i=0; i<this.length; i++ ) {
        console.log( this[i] );
        if( $.inArray( this[i], xs ) == -1 ) allIn = false;
    }
if ( allIn ){
    alert("You Won Bruh");
```

And now it works.  I only did it for X's, not for O's...I'll leave that up to you!  You can see my jsfiddle solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HxGZE/2/

**EDIT**: my solution now works.  See the jsfiddle for proof.

Comment: I noticed that. Still a good Shot, embarrassed I didn't notice my parseint wasn't assigned to anything